# How long did it take to make "Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse"?

Tags: spider-man-into-the-spider-verse

Every news article online seems to emphasise that *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse* was made at the rate of 1 second per week, but then the movie would take 100 years to make. So that seems to be an exaggeration or maybe they spend a week on an important scene.

But even so how long did it take to actually make the movie and how does it compare to regular movies? I believe it takes about 100 days of filming to make an action movie.

Comment: You could have *a team* taking one week to produce one second of scene.. if you have a lot of teams, that's actually pretty doable. Given the numbers given by Gustavo, that works out to one week per second for a 2-3 person team. You would probably more likely have one person per second and the left overs in management and other roles.

Answer (score 2):

In an interview to the [LA Times](https://www.latimes.com/entertainment/movies/la-et-mn-spider-man-into-the-spider-verse-animation-20181227-story.html), the filmmakers said it took four years to complete.

> “But,” laughed Miller, looking back on that initial pitch as “Spider-Verse” was swinging into the second week of a successful holiday frame, “only if we can do it about Miles Morales and make it look crazy. And they said, ‘OK.’ **Four years and 800 people working on it later, here we are.**”